# Application Launcher

Tags: android, launcher

I want to Create an application for android.I want an application that when a application is clicked at first my application start then after closing my application clicked application start.
Do I create an application launcher?

Comment: Why not look at the source for the Android launcher or the sample project supplied with the SDK?

Comment: I am starter android programmer.Please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code when you finish your first application.Hope it gives you some idea

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```